# Set variable default if $_get is empty

Tags: php, xml, variables

Below is the code i'm using for one of my page, but i want to set default file if $_GET['file'] doesn't exist.

```
$catalogfile = $_GET['file'];
$catalogfileend = "Product_Catalog.xml";
$xmlfile = $catalogfile . $catalogfileend;
$startPage = $_GET['page'];
```

Comment: Why are people -1ing my question? Doesn't my question make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nice also to check that $_GET['file'] is not empty and is string

```
$catalogfile = !empty($_GET['file']) && is_string($_GET['file']) ? 
    $_GET['file'] : 'defaultFile';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$catalogfile = isset($_GET['file']) && file_exists($_GET['file'])
    ? $_GET['file'] : 'defaultfile';
```

Comment: no you got me wrong, I've file like dispaly.php and i use it like display.php?file=xmlfile.xml , What I'm saying is if i just put dispaly.php I want to set some default file there so my page won't show any error

Comment: @KhushwantSingh that's what `defaultfile` is supposed to be

Comment: @KhushwantSingh, the answer above does what you're asking it to.

Comment: Wouldn't this open up for all kinds of attacks? Assign the filename to a variable like this htmlspecialchars($_GET["file"]) and use that. Isn't that safer?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` offers no special protection here. You would have to make sure that the php user running this script can only access certain files (perhaps it's restricted to a particular directory) so that you don't reveal the contents of secure files, but there's no risk of injection in the above code specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$catalogfile = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : "DEFAULT File";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
$catalogfile = 'defaultfile';
if (isset($_GET['file']) && file_exists($_GET['file'])) {
    $catalogfile = $_GET['file'];
}
```

for better readability.